# How do I find the kernel version, Ubuntu release and disk partition information from the terminal?

Tags: command-line

Which commands will give me information about following using Terminal?

1. Kernel Version
2. Distribution version no.
3. All partition size of the HDD

Comment: `hostnamectl status` will show -kernal version and distribution

Comment: @user44517. that command was not present in 2012.

Answer (score 400, accepted):

- `uname -a` for all information regarding the kernel version,

  `uname -r` for the exact kernel version
- `lsb_release -a`for all information related to the Ubuntu version,

  `lsb_release -r` for the exact version
- `sudo fdisk -l` for partition information with all details.

  <sub>For more understandable information regarding paritions, please use commands given in other answers.</sub>

Comment: Not correct `uname -a` return all not just kernel version  also `lsb_release -a` return all not only Ubuntu version moreover `sudo fdisk -l` return the block numbers and size and not human readable information

Comment: It's a great answer, however, instead of all the information (-a option switch used in Web-E's answer) you can just get the specific numbers. This is much less confusing for a beginner - For this reason I prefer MrVaykadji and Hadi improvements.

Answer (score 39):

## Kernel Version

```
cat /proc/version             # detail about for the kernel image version
```

## Distribution Version

```
lsb_release -a
```

## Partition Sizes

```
cat /proc/partitions          # for basic sizes
sudo fdisk -l /dev/<device>   # eg /dev/sda
```

Comment: +1 for the `cat /proc/version`

Answer (score 24):

### Commands:

- Kernel Version:

  ```
  uname -r
  ```
- Distribution version number:

  ```
  lsb_release -sr
  ```
- All partition sizes of the HDD in Terminal:

  ```
  lsblk -o NAME,SIZE
  ```

### Example:

> [image: example]

Comment: what terminal is that? how did you get that triangle?

Comment: it's a bashrc modification with default unity terminal. The triangle is in the characters table.

Answer (score 10):

Kernel version is:

```
uname -r
```

Ubuntu release version is:

```
lsb_release -r
```

All partition size of the HDD in Terminal

```
df -ht ext4
```

replace ext4 with your FS type if it's not so

---

**With respect to the marked as answer post:**

Not correct `uname -a` return all not just kernel version  also `lsb_release -a` return all not only Ubuntu version moreover `sudo fdisk -l` return the block numbers and size and not human readable information

Answer (score 6):

Open terminal.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo fdisk -l; uname -a; lsb_release -a
```

Answer (score 4):

uname -r

sudo fdisk -l

lsb_release -a

Answer (score 2):

To find the exact distribution, that is Ubuntu 16.04.1 or Ubuntu 16.04.3 you would use

```
lsb_release -d
```