# How to find the exact kernel version an Ubuntu release is using?

Tags: 12.04, kernel

Suppose I have a particular release of Ubuntu (say [Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS - Precise Pangolin](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.5/)). The kernel it uses is 3.13.0-32-generic x86_64. Where exactly does this version number come from? It is clearly not mainline kernel version 3.13. By looking at `/usr/include/linux/version.h` in 12.04.5 I found `LINUX_VERSION_CODE 197199` that translates to 3.2.79, which looks more plausible, but there is also mainline [v3.2.79-precise](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.2.79-precise/) which seems to correspond to v3.2.79. Is this equivalent to 12.04.5s 3.13.0-32 kernel?

How can I find out the exact mainline kernel, a particular version of Ubuntu is based on? I'm interested in finding out how to get to this 3.13.0-32 using the exact mainline kernel commit it uses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of Ubuntu Versions with Corresponding Linux Kernel Version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517136/list-of-ubuntu-versions-with-corresponding-linux-kernel-version)

Comment: "how to get to this 3.13.0-32 using the exact mainline kernel commit it uses" doesn't make sense, since Canonical backports patches (and may even have out-of-tree patches), so there's no way to get from the kernel commit to that number. Also: `linux/version.h` is from `linux-libc-dev`, so it may or may not have any relation to the kernel you're actually using.

Answer (score 2):

`uname -a` or `uname -r` might be what you are looking for. See also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183515/how-do-i-find-the-kernel-version-ubuntu-release-and-disk-partition-information#183519) and [the man page for uname](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man2/uname.2.html).

Comment: I think this is a typo, you must be referring to `uname`

Comment: Oh yes. Supposed to be uname. I think my spellcheck changed it.

Answer (score 1):

From John Ford's comment to an answer in NObert's link, the mapping you want is 
[Ubuntu kernel to mainline map](http://people.canonical.com/~kernel/info/kernel-version-map.html)
According to that, your 3.13.0-32 Ubuntu kernel is mainline 3.13.11.4

Comment: so ignore `LINUX_VERSION_CODE 197199` in `/usr/include/linux/version.h`? The closest I could find in the kernel git is [v3.13.11](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tag/?h=v3.13.11) omitting the 4.